# Anchor Tags Not Working

Tags: html, anchor

I am making a page where I want the links from my navigation to jump to their corresponding anchor tags in the page, however when I click the links the page does not jump at all.

The code for my page is here: 
https://github.com/harlanplatz/harlanplatz.github.io/blob/gh-pages/index.html

I have worked with anchor tags before and am not sure why this may not be working.

Comment: Please link directly to the file where you implement your <a> tags.

Comment: Sorry! There it is now updated

Answer (score 0):

OK Thanks Justin, it looks like you are just missing some linkage in your named anchor (`<a></a>`) tags.

Remember that you must `name` your destination anchor `<a>` tag.  So:

`<a name='example'><h1>Cool story bruh</h1</a>`

Then, to link to it, make sure you use `#anchorname` in your link `<a>` tag.  So:

`<a href='#example'>Read a cool story</a>`.

So you are matching the part after the `#` in your link href to the `name` attribute in the anchor you want to jump to.  I don't see this going on in your HTML.

Comment: I just tried this however it does not appear to be working. Updated code in the github.

Comment: can you point me to a working example of the page?  I checked your code and that definitely should be working.  It's possible you need to clear your browser cache?